# Google indexes both Amazon public dns and elastic ip

Tags: amazon-ec2, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip

I'm using an Elastic IP and have created an A record of my domain to that IP. (Host=@ and "Points to" is the IP)

Google has indexed this domain accordingly but it also has indexed the public DNS (ec2-...amazonaws.com).

I assume Google will ding me for duplicate content, have I done something wrong?

Should I have a redirect in my htaccess of ec2...amazonaws.com to my domain name?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Google mostly ignored the `amazonaws.com` domain for purposes of duplicate content. A canonical domain redirect never hurts, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I suggest you put in a redirect for anything that is not your canonical domain.

If you are using a virtual host in Apache this is usually not a problem as it will only respond to the domains you specify in a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` directive.

Regardless, you can use mod_rewrite to be sure. See [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966827/redirecting-multiple-domains-urls-to-one-canonical-domain) for a good explanation.